# Как отключить прогресс бар в google colab при тренировке нейронной сети

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory, deep-learning

Тренирую нн в гугл колабе:

```
model = nn.Sequential(
    ...
)

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.05)


for epoch in range(10):
    for x_train, y_train in tqdm(train_dataloader): 
        y_pred = model(x_train) 
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y_pred, y_train)  
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step() 
        optimizer.zero_grad() 

    val_accuracy = []
    with torch.no_grad():
        for x_val, y_val in tqdm(val_dataloader):
            y_pred = model(x_val) 
            val_accuracy.extend(
                (torch.argmax(y_pred, dim=-1) == y_val).numpy().tolist()
            )
```

При при этом появляются десятки загрузочных полос:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отключить данную функцию?

Comment: Удалите функцию `tqdm`. `tqdm(train_dataloader)` -> `train_dataloader`, `tqdm(val_dataloader)` -> `val_dataloader`

Comment: Я бы лично просто перенёс `tqdm` на цикл по эпохам `for epoch in tqdm(range(10)):`, в остальных местах убрать, да. На циклах, которые быстро делаются, прогресс-бар не нужен.